Rename a user in Azure Devops
I have several accounts that have been invited to an organization in Azure DevOps and which I now need to rename.
For example, some are called john.doe or Doe, John but should be called Doe, John (Contoso).
I have already deleted the accounts in Entra ID / Azure AD and also in Devop and re-invited them, but the names keep coming back and they are wrong.
A similar question was created here:
Rename a users in Azure DevOps
But that does not work (anymore).
Do you guys have an idea?

If a user account was created in Microsoft Entra ID tenant, when you invite the user into an Azure DevOps organization that has connected to the tenant, it will use the display name set in the tenant by default.
However, the users themselves can go to their Azure DevOps Profile Page to set a different display name to overwrite the default one. Any of other sites and applications which are referencing this Azure DevOps Profile Page will use the display name set here.
The display name changed on the Azure DevOps Profile Page will not affect the one in the Microsoft Entra ID tenant.
So, for your case, you can ask the users to login the Azure DevOps organization and then go to their Azure DevOps Profile Page to change the display name to be the expected one by themselves.


The problem is: The "Display Name" from AAD/Entra will be ignored and pulled from thin air (some caching on devops or something like that).
I told them to change it and they did it wrong. They did "John Doe (Contoso)". To avoid that I wanted to do it myself :)

@itsecharry, Each user can only edit himself/herself Azure DevOps Profile Page, and cannot edit that of other users. If you want to edit another user's Profile Page, you need to login Azure DevOps with his/her account and password.

@itsecharry, You can change their Display Name to be the correct ones in Microsoft Entra ID tenant on Azure Portal, then ask the users to login the tenant on Azure Portal to copy themselves correct Display Name and then paste the Display Name to themselves Azure DevOps Profile Page. So, this should be able to let the Display Name on Azure DevOps be consistent with that in the tenant.

@itsecharry, Is it working for you that asking the users to update their display names on themselves Azure DevOps Profile Pages following the correct display names set on Azure Portal?

because it is the only way so far, yes. Thank you.
